# How to loop through this and echo this

Tags: php, foreach, query-string

localhost/getphp.php?item[]=Bag&Price=250&Quantity=30&item[]=Charger&   Price=300&Quantity=35

```
 var_dump($_GET['item']);

 array (size=2)
    0 => string 'Bag' (length=3)
    1 => string 'Charger' (length=7)
```

but i want all values for each item and their values.

Comment: devise a grouping name instead: `item[0][name]=bag&item[0][price]=250` and so on

Comment: how to loop through this?

Comment: additional hint: you'll need to setup your form to make your url in that structure, so that when its submitted, its in that format, then the rest is a simple foreach

Answer (score 4):

You can not get all data of each product from passing these values without binding.

Use this:

```
localhost/getphp.php?item[0][item]=Bag&item[0][price]=100&item[0][quantity]=1&item[1][item]=Purse&item[1][price]=250&item[1][quantity]=6
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers you need to bind the values as follows

```
localhost/getphp.php?item[0]['name']=Bag&item[0]['price']=250&item[0]['quantity']=30&item[0]['name']=Charger&item[0]['price']=300&item[0]['quantity']=35
```

and then you can loop through it and get the values by index.

```
<?php
 $item_array = $_GET['item'];

 for($i=0; $i<count($item_array); $i++){
  echo 'Name: ' . $item_array[$i]['name']. '</br>';
  echo 'Price: ' . $item_array[$i]['price']. '</br>';
  echo 'Quantity: ' . $item_array[$i]['quantity']. '</br>';
 }
?>
```